# From my REST service, what is the best way to determine the host information of the caller?

Tags: java, rest, host

Should I be obtaining "Host" from the request headers? 
I apparently have access to HttpHeaders and HttpServletRequest.

Comment: Host will be the address of your server machine (the domain in the url they requested) not the remote host.

Answer (score 0):

HTTPServletRequest.getRemoteAddr() will return the remote IP address.